# Is there a standard for JST/Molex low voltage digital connector pin configuration?

Tags: cables, cable-assemblies

I am wondering if there is a standard for JST/Molex cable assemblies' pin configuration.
I know there are three types of ethernet/CAT cables: Straight, Cross-over and Rollover.
Does something like this exist for low-voltage JST/Molex (or any manufacturer) connectors?

Example: (Straight)

| CON 1 | CON 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |

(Rollover)

| CON 1 | CON 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |

Thanks!

Edit: Tables were not markdown, format fix

Comment: I don't think a rollover cable has anything to do with Ethernet or CAT cables. Also why would someone make cables with some types of pre-defined pinout as standard? How would a manufacturer would even know how the cable is used in order to make it a cross-over?

Comment: "ethernet" is a defined electrical standard.   "JST" and "Molex" are connector manufacturers, not standards.   So the answer is "no", you are free to define any pin-out you want on any connector.  You need to understand your APPLICATION, not the makers of the components.

Answer (score 0):

Straight (1-to-1) is preferable for assembly and troubleshooting.  For example, pin 1 is ground and a black wire, pin 2 is power and red wire.  If the pinout is the same on both sides of the cable, then the assembler doesn't need to think which end of the cable goes to which connector.  Then the troubleshooter knows that the red wire is always power, because there's no wrong way to plug in the cable.

Here's an [example](https://www.flickr.com/photos/46038819@N07/15722721032/in/dateposted-public/).  All of the cable assemblies which have the same connector on each end have straight pin assignment.

[We are dealing with general purpose cable assemblies.  If some communication  standard prescribes a certain pinout, then follow that pinout. ]